# HTTP mp4 filetransfer. IE downloads file too fast

Tags: http, internet-explorer, video, mp4

I have a web server that serves mp4 files. When I get a http request for a video that is 35mb, I use “send()” repeatedly in a loop to send 1mb each time.

Chrome and Firefox handle this well and receive no more data than needed. Only if the user has reached far enough in the webplayer, the browser requests/receives more data. IE however, receives my "send()" every two seconds, which means the entire file is downloaded in about a minute. That is not good for a user who only watched 1 min of 14 (considering data consumption/useage).

Can I do something differently?

Best regards
Arre

Comment: How do you use "send()" to download the file? Could you please provide some code to elaborate the issue? You could refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to create a minimal, reproducible sample so that we can test it and see how to help. Besides,   have you used F12 dev tools to debug the code and is there any error in console?